# C# how to programmatically launch an instance of a project with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2019, project

In Visual Studio 2019 I have a solution in which a project has to launch another project always in the same solution.
I surely could launch the deployed instance but by doing so I wouldn't have the last updated one.

So my question is: how can I **programmatically with code launch a project** just like doing DEBUG--->LAUNCH NEW INSTANCE with the mouse?

In the *Debugger*.... clas in don't see anything useful.

Thanks for helping

Patrick

[image]

Comment: You do not "launch an instance of a project". You launch an executable, i.e. the build result of a project. And you need to know in which directory it is located .

Comment: You can set solution properties to multiple start projects. Won't that work for you?

Comment: Hi, @ Patrick.
What does your "I surely could launch the deployed instance but by doing so I wouldn't have the last updated one." mean? 
Does the "last updated file" mean that the re-build must be done before it starts? 
If it is an exe that starts a project in the same solution, you can try to start the project by referring to [ProcessStartInfo.FileName Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.filename?view=netframework-4.8) to set the location of the project.exe file.

Comment: @Andy no because the launch has to be done programmatically and passing parameters that can change at any time

Comment: @HuiLiu-MFST I am working on a solution as development. Then I have the deployed and installed project executable. Obviously the developement is more updated than the installed version. So if I launche the installed version 1. I can't debug it, 2. it is not updated

Comment: @Clemens you are right. I was referring to what is shown in the image. But as a matter of fact I am afraid that this is not doable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is OLE automation.
I do not know that this is built in anymore.

If it is VS 2019 will provide a type library somewhere in its home directory that allows you to launch and automate visual studio's interface.

If you're just trying to provide debugging information maybe mshost (sp ?) has a connection protocal that allows you to catch errors as they occur.

Comment: So in short what I want is not feasible. Correct?

Comment: Answer is I don't know for certain if they removed it, but this is where I'd start.

Comment: Its always possible I think to send keystrokes to the process or used to be but I don't think you'd be able to get feedback that way.

Comment: and well.. you could find an assembly debugger that understands win32 executable images and well.. add.. some... stuff. maybe decompile it... even though that would be a mess and i would not suggest this because there is a questionable legality of such things but theoretically such things are possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key to the problem is to rebuild another project while running one project, we typically have project references. When you include a project reference, the dll will build with the rest of your app.

Project A (rebuildstartinstance):

The xaml code:

```
<Grid>
        <TextBox Width="100" Height="50" Background="AliceBlue" FontSize="29">hello</TextBox>
        <Button Height="50" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="Button_Click">click</Button>
  </Grid>
```

The cs code:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;
namespace rebuildstartinstance
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\...\\ WpfApp1\\bin\\Debug\\WpfApp1.exe";
            p.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Note : After build and run, the generated .exe file is placed in your project's bin folder. Check if you are running that .exe file.
You might also check if the .exe file's creation date is updated after compilation. If not, you are not running the right .exe file.

[image]

Project B (WpfApp1):

The xaml code:

```
<StackPanel>
        <TextBox Width="100" Height="50" Background="DarkViolet" FontSize="29">hello</TextBox>
        <TextBox Width="100" Height="50" Background="Cornsilk" FontSize="29">hello</TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Right-click References under the project A( rebuildstartinstance) ->Add Reference...->Select Projects->Check project B (WpfApp1)->click ok.

Update B project:

```
<StackPanel>
        <TextBox Width="100" Height="50" Background="DarkViolet" FontSize="29">hello</TextBox>
        <TextBox Width="100" Height="50" Background="Cornsilk" FontSize="29">hello</TextBox>
        <TextBox Width="100" Height="50" Background="DarkGreen" FontSize="29">hello</TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

The results of running project A and clicking the button are as follows:

[image]

Comment: Apologies for not having understood the purpose of your comment. I can MANUALLY launch a project when another one is running. And through the debugger class I can break execution. So why can't I launch a second project? Please note that the answer can also be that this is not doable.